# Tab components not getting displayed when used Custom Viewpager

Tags: android

I created a customViewPager class to block swiping between the tabs.Swiping has been disabled but the UI components inside the tabs are not being displayed.

Here is the CustomViewPager.java file.

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private boolean enabled;
    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context,attrs);
        this.enabled = true;


    }

    public CustomViewPager(Context context){
        super(context);
        this.enabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        if(this.enabled){
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
        if(this.enabled){
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled){
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

Here is the MainActivity.java file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener{

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    public static int swipe = 0;
    private CustomViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //Adding toolbar to the activity
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        //Initializing the tablayout
        tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab3"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        viewPager  = (CustomViewPager)findViewById(R.id.mViewPager);
        Pager adapter= new   
        Pager(getSupportFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);



        //Adding onTabSelectedListener to swipe views
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {


            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
}
```

Here is Tab1.java file

```
package com.example.nitesh.finaltab;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by Nitesh on 2/6/2017.
 */
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    int click = 0;
    View view;
    Button button;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,     
    Bundle savedInstanceState){
         view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
        button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Button is clicked","Tab1");
                if(click == 0){

                MainActivity.swipe = 1;
                click = 1;
                }

                else if(click == 1){
                    MainActivity.swipe = 0;
                    click = 0;
                }
            }
        });

        return view;

    }
}
```

Here is the activity_main.xml file

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="com.example.nitesh.finaltab.MainActivity">


    <!-- our toolbar -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id = "@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight =  "?attr/actionBarSize"        
        />


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id = "@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

      <!-- View pager to swipe views -->`

      <com.example.nitesh.finaltab.CustomViewPager
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/mViewPager"
        android:layout_height="0dp">               
      </com.example.nitesh.finaltab.CustomViewPager>
      </LinearLayout>
```

Am seeing just an empty Tab on selecting tab1. Please point out the mistake which i am doing.

Comment: What is your adapter doing? The adapter you supply to the ViewPager is very important! Can you post your code for the Pager class

Comment: Here is the code for pager Class